# redhawk yum repository 2.0.5 libbulkio on 64bit Centos6

Tags: repository, centos6, redhawksdr

I'm trying to update the redhawk-yum repository on 64bit CentOS6.  Using the redhawk-yum-2.0.5-el6-x86_64.tar.gz repository I get the following error from yum.

```
Error: Package: rh.SourceVITA49-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64 (@/rh.SourceVITA49-3.0.1-2.el6.x86_64)
       Requires: libbulkio-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
       Removing: bulkioInterfaces-2.0.4-6.el6.x86_64 (@redhawk)
           libbulkio-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
       Updated By: bulkioInterfaces-2.1.0-3.el6.x86_64 (redhawk)
           Not found
```

I haven't been able to track down where to get the libbulkio library file.

Comment: Could you clarify to indicate which version you have installed, and which you're updating to?

Comment: Currently installed is redhawk-yum-2.0.4-el6-x86_64.tar.gz.  I'm trying to update to redhawk-yum-2.0.5-el6-x86_64.tar.gz.  I hope this is the version info you need.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some issue in the steps you are taking to perform the update or setup the yum repos. I was unable to recreate the issue. Here are the steps I took which worked. If you have docker installed the following steps should all work for you as well.

I drop myself into an updated centos 6 container

```
ylb@Atlas:~$ docker run -it --rm centos:6 bash -l
```

I install the epel repo and a couple dependencies I'll need to unzip and untar the release artifacts

```
[root@3580f228f9fe /]# yum install -y tar gzip yum-utils epel-release
```

Create a directory to hold the yum repos and curl and untar the 2.0.4 yum repo.

```
[root@3580f228f9fe /]# mkdir -p /tmp/yum/
[root@3580f228f9fe /]# cd /tmp/yum/
[root@3580f228f9fe /]# curl -L https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/redhawk/releases/download/2.0.4/redhawk-yum-2.0.4-el6-x86_64.tar.gz | tar xzf -
```

I used yum-config-manager to add the local yum repo to `/etc/yum.repos.d/`, this does not add the gpgcheck=0 so on future calls to yum I simply ignore gpgcheck. Not recommended for a real system but this is just an example

```
[root@3580f228f9fe yum]# yum-config-manager --add-repo=file:///tmp/yum/redhawk-2.0.4-el6-x86_64/
```

Now install all the redhawk assets and libraries using both the runtime and development group installs

```
[root@3580f228f9fe yum]# yum groupinstall -y --nogpgcheck "REDHAWK Runtime" "REDHAWK Development"
```

Now that it is installed we can repeat the process using the 2.0.5 release and simply run a `yum update` to pull in any updated redhawk assets.

```
[root@3580f228f9fe /]# curl -L https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/redhawk/releases/download/2.0.5/redhawk-yum-2.0.5-el6-x86_64.tar.gz | tar xzf -
[root@3580f228f9fe yum]# yum-config-manager --add-repo=file:///tmp/yum/redhawk-2.0.5-el6-x86_64/
[root@3580f228f9fe yum]# yum update --nogpgcheck
```

I have not posted the output of the commands but the following redhawk assets were updated when going from 2.0.4 to 2.0.5

```
Updated:
  GPP.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6                        GPP-profile.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6                     bulkioInterfaces.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6                burstioInterfaces.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6                  
  frontendInterfaces.x86_64 0:2.3.5-2.el6         libomniEvents2.x86_64 0:2.7.1-2.el6                  librtlsdr.x86_64 0:0.5.2-4.el6                       omniEvents-bootscripts.x86_64 0:2.7.1-2.el6             
  omniEvents-server.x86_64 0:2.7.1-2.el6          omniEvents-utils.x86_64 0:2.7.1-2.el6                redhawk.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6                         redhawk-basic-components.x86_64 0:2.0.5-1.el6           
  redhawk-codegen.noarch 0:2.0.5-2.el6            redhawk-debuginfo.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6               redhawk-devel.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6                   redhawk-ide.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6                        
  redhawk-qt-tools.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6           redhawk-sdrroot-dev-mgr.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6         redhawk-sdrroot-dom-mgr.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6         redhawk-sdrroot-dom-profile.x86_64 0:2.0.5-2.el6        
  rh.FileWriter.x86_64 0:4.0.3-1.el6              rh.RedhawkDevUtils.x86_64 0:4.0.1-2.el6              rh.SourceSDDS.x86_64 0:1.1.0-1.el6                   rh.blueFileLib.x86_64 0:2.0.1-1.el6                     
  rh.fastfilter.x86_64 0:2.0.1-1.el6              rh.psd.x86_64 0:2.0.2-2.el6
```

Comment: I agree with Youssef that you shouldn't have any update problems from 2.0.4 to 2.0.5. I believe your system is configured for updates from a Redhawk 2.1.0 yum repository. Based on the message, you're getting a conflict between a component (rh.SourceVITA49, probably built for 2.0.5), and the fact that yum is trying to upgrade the BULKIO library to 2.1.0 (that's what the bulkioInterfaces-2.1.0-3 is, and why you'd end up missing libbulkio-2.0.so.0).

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to look into this.  I made no changes to my setup but found that my "yum update" command worked fine this morning.  I have no explanation, though I had rebooted a couple times in the interim.